# How do I solve this matrix equation for infinitesimal rotations?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, nonlinear

I have a matrix equation, taken from [Wikipedia (Infinitesimale Drehungen)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drehmatrix#Infinitesimale_Drehungen), that looks not that complicated (note $a$ is a scalar, actually an angle as input paramter for the rotation matrix):

$$
R(a)=\exp(aJ)
$$

In my case I would like to obtain $J$ while $R(a)$ is given:
$$
R(a)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\left(\sqrt{5}a\right)&-\frac{2\sin\left(\sqrt{5}a\right)}{\sqrt{5}}&\frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{5}a\right)}{\sqrt{5}}\\
\frac{2\sin\left(\sqrt{5}a\right)}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{5}\left(4\cos\left(\sqrt{5}a\right)+1\right) & -\frac{2}{5}\left(\cos\left(\sqrt{5}a\right)-1\right)\\
-\frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{5}a\right)}{\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{2}{5}\left(\cos\left(\sqrt{5}a\right)-1\right) & \frac{1}{5}\left(\cos\left(\sqrt{5}a\right)+4\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I tried the following `J[a_] := MatrixLog[R[a]]/a` which does not work. Based on the equation $J=\left.\frac{dR(a)}{da}\right|_{a=0}$ that is also provided on the above-given Wikipedia page, I tried `J[a_] := D[R[a], a]` as well, which did not worked too.

My full listing looks as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
R[a_] := {{Cos[\[Sqrt]5 a], -((2 Sin[\[Sqrt]5 a])/(\[Sqrt]5)), Sin[\[Sqrt]5 a]/(\[Sqrt]5)},
   {(2 Sin[\[Sqrt]5 a])/(\[Sqrt]5), (1/5) (1 + 4 Cos[\[Sqrt]5 a]), -(2/5) (-1 + Cos[\[Sqrt]5 a])},
   {-(Sin[\[Sqrt]5 a]/(\[Sqrt]5)), -(2/5) (-1 + Cos[\[Sqrt]5 a]), (1/5) (4 + Cos[\[Sqrt]5 a])}};
J[a_] := MatrixLog[R[a]]/a;
J[a_] := D[R[a], a];
FullSimplify[MatrixExp[a*J]]
FullSimplify[Limit[MatrixPower[IdentityMatrix[3] + (a/n) J, n], n -> Infinity]]
```

The last two `Print` statements should yield the original matrix $R(a)$.
I would be greatful for any help on obtaining the Matrix $J$.

Comment: `Asymptotic[R[a] - MatrixExp[a R'[a]] // Simplify, a -> 0]` shows that expression is small `O[a^2]`

Comment: With a quick look, it seems to me the notation is a bit inconsistent, ie $a$ is in a dot product with $J$ in the 1st equation (hence is a matrix), but then appears as a scalar later on. I think this should be clarified before any attempts at a solution are made ;-)

Comment: You are right - $a$ is a scalar (an angle actually). And I fixed it in the OP to be treated consistently as a scalar.

Comment: Ok, thanks it's then more clear.

Comment: The use of `Print` is unnecessary in expressions like `Print[FullSimplify[MatrixExp[a*J]]];` Just don't suppress the output with the semi-colon.

Comment: Good point - I fixed it in the script above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, Mathematica is strict when using multivalued functions (like `Log`), and that is why it won't fully "simplify" your expression unless you use some tricky functions (like `PowerExpand` or `ComplexExpand`).

The following works:

```
Clear[R, J];
R[a_] := {{Cos[\[Sqrt]5 a], -((2 Sin[\[Sqrt]5 a])/(\[Sqrt]5)), 
    Sin[\[Sqrt]5 a]/(\[Sqrt]5)}, {(2 Sin[\[Sqrt]5 a])/(\[Sqrt]5), (1/
       5) (1 + 4 Cos[\[Sqrt]5 a]), -(2/5) (-1 + 
       Cos[\[Sqrt]5 a])}, {-(Sin[\[Sqrt]5 a]/(\[Sqrt]5)), -(2/5) (-1 +
        Cos[\[Sqrt]5 a]), (1/5) (4 + Cos[\[Sqrt]5 a])}};

J = PowerExpand[FullSimplify[(MatrixLog[R[a]]/a)]];
J // MatrixForm
```

[image: result]

Check the result:

```
MatrixExp[a J] == R[a] // Reduce
(* True *)
```

Comment: Works brilliantly: `Print[FullSimplify[MatrixExp[a*J]]]` yields the original matrix. Many thanks!

Comment: Just to provide a double-check: the limit-based equation `FullSimplify[Limit[MatrixPower[IdentityMatrix[3] + (a/n) J, n], n -> Infinity]]` yields the original rotation matrix as well.

Answer (score 4):

The derivative formula you found,
$$
\left.\frac{dR}{da}\right|_{a=0} =  J,
$$
is much easier to use than the `MatrixLog` functions;  you
just neglected to set $a$ to zero after you took the derivative.  This can be done like so:

```
J = D[R[a], a] /. a -> 0
(* {{0, -2, 1}, {2, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}} *)
```

Verifying:

```
Simplify[MatrixExp[a J] == R[a]] 
(* True *)

Simplify[Limit[MatrixPower[IdentityMatrix[3] + (a/n) J, n], n -> Infinity] == R[a]]
(* True *)
```

Alternately, the matrix exponential is *defined* in such a way that
$$
\frac{dR}{da} = J R(a) \quad \Rightarrow \quad J = R^{-1} \frac{dR}{da}
$$
which can also be done in Mathematica:

```
J = Simplify[Inverse[R[a]] . D[R[a], a]] 
(* same as above *)
```

Comment: This is really a very efficient alternative, which I also just tried and works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach that might be useful in some cases.

You can compute the `MatrixLog` in the limit of small `a`

```
Limit[MatrixLog[Normal[Series[R[a], {a, 0, 1}]]]/a, a -> 0]
(* {{0, -2, 1}, {2, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for this interesting approach, which works greatly as well. Do you have a reference (maybe wiki or math book) for this trick? On [Wikipedia Page for Matrix Log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix) I could not find it.

Comment: Your relationship is true for all values of `a` so it must be true in the limiting value of small `a`.